# How to make rendered HTML from Java Play 2 "beautiful"

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Please help me to make rendered HTML from Java Play 2 "beautiful", like Tidy in PHP.

The "beautiful" is stand for something like [**this**](http://www.cleancss.com/html-beautify/).

I only know how to make it "beautiful" in PHP, but not in Java, more precisely in Play 2.

I use ".scala.html" to build the views.

FYI, this is some information about my env :

```
Play: 2.5.3
Scala: 2.11.7
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: @m-z You can understand what i mean, if you know about Tidy. The purpose is something like this http://www.cleancss.com/html-beautify/. Or maybe like this jsbeautifier.org in JS.

Comment: @nabilftd Just out of curiosity: why you need to beautify the html? If you want to display nicely formatted html to your app users, you may want to use some javascript library to do that...

Comment: You want something to format the `.scala.html` files while developing or you want something that formats the final rendered html?

Comment: @Salem It's just about how you feel when looking at the syntax. Cus i like something "beautiful". I always make my code "beautiful", but not at the rendered.

Comment: @marcospereira No, i need the final rendered HTML to be "beautiful", not at the .scala.html. So, I give Tidy in PHP for the example. Maybe not a good example, but i only have experience in Tidy.

Comment: @nabilftd any special reason why you need that? I mean, it makes no difference at all to the browser.

Comment: @marcospereira As i said before to Salem, the reason is just about how you feel when looking at the syntax. Cus i like something "beautiful". Yes, you're right, there are no differences at the browser level.

Comment: Ok. You can use [JTidy API](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/howto.html) in combination with [Play filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters) to achieve that.

Comment: @marcospereira Aaah, make sense now. Thank you very much, I haven't thought about Filters before. I'll see it. Would be nice if you could bring the example for me :p